# How to edit files during git commit diff in Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, diff, commit

In Visual Studio while committing a file to Git it is easy to edit files directly in the diff window:

[image]

Now in Android Studio the diff window seems to be readonly:
[image]

How to edit during commit? If not possible how to simplify the following workflow:

1. Close commit window
2. Find the file
3. Edit
4. Open commit window
5. Find the file
6. Next edit
7. Repeat 1-6

Or writing the changes on paper or notepad and then editing them at once.

Comment: You know that Android Studio bases on IntelliJ and therefor also includes the IntelliJ scripting support? See for example https://gist.github.com/gregsh/b7ef2e4ebbc4c4c11ee9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works by double clicking the files in the commit window: It opens a new edit window for the file.